# Error: Overpass query unavailable without internet while connected to internet

Tags: r, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am getting an error while trying to use osmdata package. I removed package and re-installed it and still get the weird error. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
library(osmdata)    
tehran <- opq(bbox = 'Tehran, Iran') %>%
      add_osm_feature(key = 'admin_level', value = '9') %>% 
      osmdata_sf %>% 
      unique_osmdata 

#Error: Overpass query unavailable without internet

head(available_features())
#No internet connection
```

This is strange since I can install new packages and use rvest that means I have access to internet through rstudio. I removed the package and re-installed and didn't work. I also updated curl package and returned same results. Here is the session info:

> R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: Linux Mint 20
> Matrix products: default
> BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
> LAPACK:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The package uses `curl::has_internet()`, see here: https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/243

You can check this answers: [R curl::has_internet() FALSE even though there are internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796178/r-curlhas-internet-false-even-though-there-are-internet-connection)

This would probably help, if you have an internet connection but curl does not detect it:

```
assign("has_internet_via_proxy", TRUE, environment(curl::has_internet))
```